# hashed passwords are not being saved with pre save hook in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Postman to test an API that I am working on for a project.  I am sending

```
{
    "fullName": "Smellydog",
    "emailAddress": "SmellydogCoding@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "confirmPassword": "password"
}
```

as the request body to this API route

```
users.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let user = new Users(req.body);
  user.save((error,user) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      res.status = 201;
      res.location('/');
      res.end();
    }
  });
});
```

This is my Users Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    emailAddress: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      match: [emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email address"],
      trim: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    confirmPassword: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
});

// hash password before saving to database
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next)  {
  bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, function(error, hash) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      this.password = hash;
      this.confirmPassword = hash;
      next();
    }
  });
});

UserSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
  let user = this;
  if (user.password !== user.confirmPassword) {
    return next('Passwords must match');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

The pre save hook is supposed to encrypt the password and then save it to the password and confirmPassword fields.  If I use Chrome debugger to set a breakpoint at the end of the pre save hook (where next() is called), and inspect this.password and this.confirmPassword, I see that they are set to the newly created hash, but when I check the database afterwards both of those fields are set to the original password string

```
{
    "_id": "58d835f0d026194610578c74",
    "fullName": "Smellydog",
    "emailAddress": "SmellydogCoding@gmail.com",
    "password": "password",
    "confirmPassword": "password",
    "__v": 0
  }
```

Comment: have you tried logging the second "this.password"? i think that the context has changed and is not the same as the first you have called.

Comment: When I do a console.log on this.password and this.confirmPassword (right before next() ) it outputs the hashed password: $2a$10$EZD1zuECinDfdQLxvTGjhe8mgCV8Kn7Eprssev5967A0Qch75xE3K  database is still storing it as plain text

Comment: you should log it before setting it equal to hash! it should return the decrypted password, otherwise you are setting hash to a new variable. try to use the arrow function to keep the same context of the outer function.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answer made by smellyDogCoding. The reason why the solution works is because of the context of this. When the thread of execution hits the line:
`let user =this`

The context of 'this' is referring to an instance of the document being created. However, once we enter the execution context of the bcrypt hash method, the 'this' context no longer refers to the instance of the document we're creating in the database, but instead refers to the scope of the function.

By saving a reference to the instance of the document object we are creating in a variable, user, we retain a reference to the this we want to update after hashing. And since we're only making a shallow copy--really a reference to the original this, when we update the property 'password' on the user object, we're also updating the property 'password' on the 'this' document object.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are using

```
bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, function(error, hash)
```

the `.hash` method asynchronous, which means you are running the `next()` function before the password is hashed.

use async/await instead

```
UserSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  // check if password is present and is modified.
  try {
    if (this.password && this.isModified('password')) {
      this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, passwordSaltRound);
    }
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

with your method you can use `bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 10, function(error, hash)` but it will create blocking code!

so just use the async/await method <3

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
let user = this;
```

to the first line of the pre save hook and then referred to the fields as

```
user.password
user.confirmPassword
```

like so

```
// hash password before saving to database
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next)  {
  let user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(error, hash) {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      user.password = hash;
      user.confirmPassword = hash;
      next();
    }
  });
});
```

It seems that this.password was being updated while inside the pre save hook but it was not being persisted to the database at the end.  Setting this to a variable seems to change the context as Paolo has suggested.  I would really love to know the how and why of this.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but I would like to say that another solution for this is to use arrow function expressions introduced in ES6.

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next)  {
  bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10, (error, hash) => {
    if (error) {
      return next(error);
    } else {
      this.password = hash;
      this.confirmPassword = hash;
      next();
    }
  });
});
```

the reason why this works is because an arrow function expression does not have its own bindings to `this`, so it takes the context from where the function is defined; which is the user object's context in this case.

you can read more about arrow function on MDN Web Docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)